# Proper writing of substitutions involving integers?

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, expression-manipulation

I would like to make a substitution like the following

```
(-3 + n)!/.(-x_Integer + n)!:>a
```

where I expect `a` to be the output. Unfortunately, Mathematica 10 just returns

> (-3 + n)!

I even tried

```
(-3 + n)!/.Factorial[Plus[-x_Integer,n]]:>a
```

And the result is still

> (-3 + n)!

What am I doing wrong? How to make this substitution work?

Comment: What does `MatchQ[-3, -x_Integer]` tell you?

Comment: It works if you leave out the minus, i.e. `(-3 + n)!/.Factorial[Plus[x_Integer,n]]:>a` because Mathematica recognizes the negative integer as integer too. If you only want negative values to match, you could do `x_?(IntegerQ[#]&&Negative[#]&)`

Comment: Thanks, good to know! Guess I'll just do `/. (x_Integer + n)! /; x < 0:>a`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When having problems with a replacement rule, use [**`FullForm`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) to understand the patterns involved

```
(-3+n)!//FullForm

(*  Factorial[Plus[-3,n]]  *)

(-x_Integer+n)!//FullForm

(*  Factorial[Plus[n,Times[-1,Pattern[x,Blank[Integer]]]]]  *)
```

You can use

```
{(-3+n)!,(3+n)!}/.(_Integer+n)!:>a

(*  {a,a}  *)
```

Or, if the rule is only to apply for negative integers then use

```
{(-3+n)!,(3+n)!}/.(_Integer?Negative+n)!:>a

(*  {a,(3+n)!}  *)
```